# Flask application failing on Heroku: no module named app

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have a Flask application that I have deployed to Heroku, but I get an error:

```
2018-08-27T12:39:32.197715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=heroku-seb-test.herokuapp.com request_id=3e02d494-1a3f-4467-9eaa-aaa551b4ca03 fwd="91.143.113.54" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

It appears that it is a mistake in my Flask app structure, because just above it throws a Python / Flask exception:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app 
__import__(module)
ImportError: No module named app
```

Here is my folder structure:

- Folio

  - routes.py
  - (Procfile and other dependencies)
  - static

    - css
    - js
    - images
    - lib
  - templates

    - index.html
  - venv

Here is my `routes.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, flash, session, url_for, 
redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('index.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Procfile` tells Heroku how to run your application. `gunicorn` [expects to be given an argument in the form of `module.variable`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html) identifying the thing it should run.

Today you're telling it that your app is in a variable called `app` in a module called `app`:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

But your module isn't called `app`—it's called `routes` (the file is `routes.py`). Update your `Procfile` to point to the correct object:

```
web: gunicorn routes:app
```

Commit that change and push to Heroku to see its effect. (Or you can use [`heroku local`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local) to try it out locally.)

Comment: i did this, and i get the error 
 error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
on my heroku server

Comment: @baileyhaldwin, that's a different error. You can't bind to whatever port you want on Heroku. Instead, you should use the port that [Heroku asks you to use via the `PORT` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos). If you have trouble with that please search for more resources and if that doesn't help feel free to ask another question.

Comment: Can you do folder.app:app if app.py is inside some folder?

Comment: @makewhite, that's the kind of thing that is very easy to try on your own. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Chris Yes, and it works. If you are familiar with heroku and flask do you mind taking a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405822/heroku-error-in-app-exception-on-cities-republic-of-korea-get